# A multi-function offline calculator for Windows

Tags: windows, calculator

I am looking for an offline calculator software, similar to [calculatorsoup.com](http://www.calculatorsoup.com/): something which contains various calculators like Age, BMI, Love and others.

I use such calculators regularly and it is generally not very easy to browse for such calculators every time, and online resources are mostly full of ads.

So is anyone aware of such a software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this software recently called DubCen. It's a new software. Surprisingly, I couldn't find any similar software. You can learn more at their [website](https://www.dubcen.com) . They say it contains about 50 'good looking' calculators like Amortization, BMI, CHmod, Age, Love and others and also a unit converter..

Update : I just downloaded it and I would say that it's old idea with a new look. It also costs $10/yr. You can give it a try